# Button text on multiple lines AX2009

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

Is it possible to make the text for a button span two lines instead of just one on a form?

I have already tried inserting a line break (\n) in the text for a button, but that did not work, also when done from the code.

This is in AX2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is only something you can accomplish via X++ modification of the button properties:

```
button1.text("line 1\nline 2");
```

Will make the text on the button appear

```
line 1
line 2
```

However, in my testing I was not able to get the text to align vertically within the control (the bottom edge of the second line was cut off if the height was less than 50). I believe the only way around this would be to change the top margin of the button, but I can't find any property on the button to control this.

Comment: I have tried this already, but it did not work. I tried again now and it did not work. Where are you running this when you open the form?

Comment: interestingly enough, I'm hopping on the same framework as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787228/ax2009-loop-through-all-the-controls-in-the-form-on-init). It seems to only work when applied to the FormBuildButtonControl prior to init. I wasn't even able to replicate the result outside of the loop iteration (also prior to init).