# How to cycle the filling of Form controls?

Tags: forms, while-loop, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

In my form I have three `StringEdit` controls.

I have to fill each **Control** with values.
Is it possible to use  `while select` for all these controls and to fill them?

I have this code:

```
StringEdit1.text(strFmt("value"));
StringEdit2.text(strFmt("value"));
StringEdit3.text(strFmt("value"));
```

But I would not like to repeat the code for each **Control**.

Is it possible, to use a code that looks like the one for the **Record** , something like:

`getNext()`, `getFirst()`, etc.

This filling action should start in the form's `init` method.

Thanks for your time,

Enjoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this post that should help you loop over form controls.

The post specifically does recursion to drill down into each group, etc.  You can use the same logic though if all of your controls are on one group and just remove the recursion.

http://alexondax.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-use-recursion-to-loop-over-form.html

Just copy & paste the code into a job and run it (AX12/AX09) and it's pretty cool.

Comment: The original code to this answer is in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787228/ax2009-loop-through-all-the-controls-in-the-form-on-init

Comment: @FH-Inway - KingOfZeal and myself answered that question within minutes of each other oddly enough. Mine answer I think is better for showing "what's happening" with the infolog output and also how to use the controls.