# Dynamics AX 2012: How can I get, by code, a list of all the methods within a specific form?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Is there any way for me to get, by code, a list of all the methods in a given form in Dynamics AX 2012?

I am working in developing a small tool that will insert some comments in all of the methods of custom objects through using the Editor class. However, to do so, I need the full path of each method (ex: \Classes\MyClass\CustomMethod), but I simply can't find any way to get this working for Forms.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for sending me suggestions. I actually just finished writing some code to get me the information. Here is the code, for anyone who may be interested:

```
//I used the BatchJobHistory form as a test, since I called this static method from a job
public static void findAllChildNodes(str _nodeName = "\\Forms\\BatchJobHistory", boolean _isMethod = NoYes::No)
{
    TreeNode         treeNode;
    TreeNodeIterator treeNodeIterator;
    treeNode         methodsNode;
    str              treePath;
    boolean          containsMethod;

    treeNode = TreeNode::findNode(_nodeName);
    treeNodeIterator = treeNode.AOTiterator();
    methodsNode = treeNodeIterator.next();

    while(methodsNode)
    {
        treePath = methodsNode.treeNodePath();
        containsMethod = strScan(treePath, 'Methods', 1, strLen(treePath));

        if (methodsNode.AOTchildNodeCount())
        {
            //TestClass is the class containing this method
            TestClass::findAllChildNodes(treePath, containsMethod);
        }
        else if (_isMethod)
        {
            info(strFmt("%1", treePath));
        }

        methodsNode = treeNodeIterator.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you got something working. If you are only working with completely custom objects, you'll obviously identify your own methods, but if you've customized a base form, you'll probably need to identify if it's in a non-`SYS`/`SYP` layer. You can do this a few ways, but I like the `bitwise` method (single `&`), which seems more accurate with older AX versions `if (treeNode.applObjectLayerMask() & (1 << UtilEntryLevel::cus)) info("In CUS layer");`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a question that should point you in the right direction, albeit you'll need to expand on it.

[AX2009 Loop through all the controls in the form on init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787228/ax2009-loop-through-all-the-controls-in-the-form-on-init/23789330#23789330)

The general theme you'll probably need to work with is `recursion` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), `reflection`, and use of the `TreeNode` and derivatives of the class to do `Tree Node Traversal` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/performing-reflection-with-the-treenode-class

I'm also imagining you'll need to use some of the layer-aware methods if you're trying to decorate methods with comments. It sounds fun what you're trying to do, but a little bit of a pain. I'd expect it to take at least half a day to do properly.